# subset data frame by skipping a specific number of rows

Tags: r

i have a very big data frame((35000 line) but i want to get specific rows by skipping for example 100 row.

so in this case each 100 row I'll just get one row.

i know that it can be done using:

```
N = nrow(dataframe)
   for( i in seq(1:N,by=100))
   { 
   out <- rbind(out, data.frame(...)

    }
```

is this can be done more easily than a for loop?? using `subset` or something like this

regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
dataframe[seq(1, nrow(dataframe), 100), ]
```

Comment: Came back here to post exactly this but Andrie Ninj'd me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector and then subset on that vector like this:

```
temp <- seq(from = 1, to = N, by = 100)
df <- dataframe[temp,]
```

Comment: you need the - infront of temp like Andrie otherwise you're returning the unwanted rows.

Comment: I believe the user only wants every 100th row (not the complement of that). I think my answer is correct unless I have misunderstood the question. It appears Andrie (who beat me by a few secs) is producing the same result with one less step. Up voting for speed and efficiency.